# How to fix opening time minutes for whole week using DateTime Picker?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Using DateTimepicker I want to set store opening time as 10:30 AM (for example) for the whole week. Using this piece of code I could able to restrict hours.

```
var curentDate = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date();
lastDate.setDate(curentDate.getDate() + 6);
$('#txtdate').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    maxDate: lastDate,
    minDate: curentDate,
    enabledHours: HoursArray()
});
```

I set this to 15min increment but I'm not sure how to set minutes for all the days in a week. Also I want to disable minutes before 10:30 AM each day.

Can some one guide me on this?

Comment: Area you using this library: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ ?

Comment: @inspired - Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the library exposing any ways to set the default time for each day, but you can take control into your own hands by using their [events API](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) and [date()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method. You could listen for change event Like this:

```
$(document).on('dp.change', manipulateTime);
```

The event shows the `new date` and `oldate` of the calendar. If the dates are different then you can change the time for new date using the `date()` method.

```
function manipulateTime(e){

  if(!e.date.isSame(e.oldDate, "day")){
    $(e.target).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.set({
      'hour' : 10,
      'minute'  : 30
    }));
  }

}
```

### Further Explanation

---

The when the event fires it returns three necessary references, `date`,`olddate`,`target`.

**Calling DateTimePicker Functions**

> - Note according to their documentation you can use their methods like this: All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g.
>     $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()

**Using Events**

When you call the `dp.change` event. The call back function will return an object `e` that has the following accessible properties:

**The `e` property**

```
e = {
    date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
    oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null,
    target // targeted date picker,
    and more...
}
```

Comment: Occurring event on selecting a new day part of the library right? How to manipulate that in my JS file?

Comment: @inspited - Yes

Comment: Yeah, also It shouldn't allow user to select minutes less than that

Comment: class name of the each day are 'day'

Comment: tried this way..but event never fires $('#datetimepicker').on('click', 'td.day', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Im here');
    });

Comment: @Jaggi did you try to use the event the way i said? ive already tested it, it works.

Comment: this solution worked for me. Actually I was calling this event before initializing.

Comment: - Can you pls help me on disabling the minutes before 30?

Comment: Maybe you should disable the down arrow when the minutes are at 30. Inside the same change event, you can check the minutes. If the time is 10:30 then you can disable the down arrow

Comment: Can you give an example to disable down arrow when time is equal to 10:30?

Comment: I was trying to get time from time picker using this $('.timepicker').data("timepicker").getTime(); to compare with assigned time, but never works out. it throws getTime() is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153961/discussion-between-jaggi-and-inspired).

Answer (score 0):

This is the final thing I did to fix my both issues

```
var futureHour  = (new Date(td.date)).getHours();
var futureMin = (new Date(td.date)).getMinutes();

//This is to re-loop time when user tries to select time below 1st pickup time
              if(futureHour <= storeOpenHour && futureMin < storeOpenMinutes){
                $(td.target).data("DateTimePicker").date(td.date.set({
                  'hour' : storeOpenHour,
                  'minute'  : storeOpenMinutes
                }));
                }

                //This is to select 1st pickup time on day change
              if(!td.date.isSame(td.oldDate, "day")){
                $(td.target).data("DateTimePicker").date(td.date.set({
                  'hour' : storeOpenHour,
                  'minute'  : storeOpenMinutes
                }));
              }
```